# Listing large amount of NFTs up for English sale on Openseea

Tags: erc-721, opensea, batch

Since the release of latest Opensea API, support for English auctions has been removed ([Source](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/pull/561#discussion_r897240203)). I am therefore looking for an alternative, which would allow creating listings for large amount of NFTs.

Few things that I have tried already and came to a dead end:

1. Using the Seaport.js (waitForHighestBid isn't recognized, which results in a normal listing)
2. Using Seaport.js 3.0.4 (API doesn't support the requests from this version anymore)
3. Creating a listing on the chain via validate(). [Source](https://twitter.com/Slokh/status/1570211430904864770) (Does not actually list the NFT even when successful)
4. Sending the same kind of requests as FE (A key is generated for every request, so sending requests directly to BE results in permission denied)
5. Sending requests directly to API (doesn't work since API doesn't support the English auctions yet)

My question is if it is possible to achieve batch English auction listing in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium against opensea.com? It's less ideal but I imagine it will work

Comment: I think for something like 10k NFTs that would take way too long to list them all.

Comment: it would be ~1.5 days of code running, so assuming you're not doing 10k NFTs every day, I think it would work